# Prove Euler's theorem with Sympy

Tags: python, math, sympy, economics

[image: Euler problem]

I am trying to use Sympy for this problem, however I'm having some trouble with the code. Here's what I have so far. The error message is that "g is not a callable function".

```
from sympy import *

x, y, z, λ, m = symbols('x y z λ m',real=True)

g = Function('g')(x,y,z)

LHS = g(λ*x,λ*y,z)

RHS = (λ**m)*g(x,y,z)

expr = Eq(LHS,RHS)

display(expr)
```

Comment: don't paste pictures of code.  I can't paste it into python.

Comment: You should just use `g = Function('g')`.